# Percent of change by year and month

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have code that distinctly counts authorizations grouped by month and year.
I added a calculated field to show the percent of change but my issue is I only want to get this percentage between the years by month.
My code calculates the percent for each previous row. which when pulled into SSRS displays the incorrect value after the for column.

```
Select D.Month
        ,D.Year
        ,count( distinct D.authorization_number) [Admission Events]
        ,CAST(lag(Count(distinct D.authorization_number), 1) over (order by D.month) - Count(distinct D.authorization_number) as FLOAT) / CAST(Count(distinct D.authorization_number)as FLOAT)   [Admission Events Pct]
From #Detail D
Group BY D.Month
        ,D.Year
```

In these results I would like to only display the pct for year 2018 in SSRS.

```
Month   Year    Admission Events    Admission Events Pct
1      2017     5919                 NULL
1      2018     6057                 -0.0227835562159485
2      2017     5302                  0.142399094681252
2      2018     5234                  0.0129919755445166
3      2017     5548                 -0.0565969718817592
3      2018     5389                  0.0295045462980145
4      2017     5128                  0.0508970358814353
4      2018     5503                 -0.0681446483736144
5      2017     5768                 -0.0459431345353675
5      2018     5708                  0.0105115627189909
6      2017     5461                  0.0452298113898553
6      2018     2606                  1.09554873369148
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from (<your query here>) t
where year = 2018;
```

You need a subquery or CTE so the `where` doesn't interfere with the `lag()`.